# How symfony auto clean the HTML output?

Tags: php, symfony1, escaping, htmlspecialchars

I know it must use htmlspecialchars() but it automatic clean the output when I use echo statement. Manually, without symfony, how can I do that? Override echo statement? I know theres ob_start(), ob_get_contents() etc, but it then clean the whole output

Answer (score 1):

There's a method for outputting data in the template that bypasses the output escaping:

```
<?php echo $sf_data->getRaw('variable_name_here'); ?>
```

I think you can even output the entire template content for specific layouts using:

```
<?php echo $sf_data->getRaw('sf_content') ?>
```

The escaping settings for your app are controlled in settings.yml (all_settings_escaping_method). You should see ESC_SPECIALCHARS on by default.

Also, using...

```
<?php echo html_entity_decode($variable) ?>
```

... can help sometimes.